# Bring back the Default Search Score as part of a document

Tags: c#, azure-cognitive-search

When I search using the Azure Search Portal, I get an extra field called: "@search.score" for each document pulled back from the Search Index.

But I couldn't find any documentation about how to get that value for each row when we make use of the .NET SDK

Example:

[Search using Azure Search Portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urIx2.png)

We are using the default score profile for testing purposes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The document score is a property of the `SearchResult` class: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.search.models.searchresult-1.score?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Search_Models_SearchResult_1_Score

Instances of this class wrap each document that is returned in the results from the Search API.